# Differential equation with expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

In this problem of physical origin (Newton's equation of motion of a charged particle in an electric field), can you help me with equation (1.7)?

I get more or less where it comes from, but I could not derive it myself. Could you provide a rigorous derivation? The expansion in terms of a variable depending on other variables is what confuses me.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you're better off asking this at [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It could be, although I'm only interested in the derivation, and that is just taylor + ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Please express the mathematical difficulty so the readers don't have to go into physical problem. It is not evident that what is your mathematical problem! :)